# How to specify relationship type in CSV?

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I have a CSV file with data like:

```
ID,Name,Role,Project
1,James,Owner,TST
2,Ed,Assistant,TST
3,Jack,Manager,TST
```

and want to create people whose relationships to the project are therein specified.  I attempted to do it like this:

```
load csv from 'file:/../x.csv' as line 
match (p:Project {code: line[3]}) 
create (n:Individual {name: line[1]})-[r:line[2]]->(p);
```

but it barfs with:

> Invalid input '[': expected an identifier character, whitespace, '|',
>   a length specification, a property map or ']' (line 1, column 159
>   (offset: 158))

as it can't seem to dereference `line` in the relationship creation.  if I hard-code that it works:

```
load csv from 'file:/../x.csv' as line 
match (p:Project {code: line[3]}) 
create (n:Individual {name: line[1]})-[r:WORKSFOR]->(p);
```

so how do I make the reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you can't as this is structural information.

Either use [neo4j-import tool](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool.html) for that.

Or specify it manually as you did, or use this workaround:

```
load csv with headers from 'file:/../x.csv' as line 
match (p:Project {code: line.Project}) 
create (n:Individual {name: lineName})
foreach (x in case line.Role when "Owner" then [1] else [] end |
  create (n)-[r:Owner]->(p)
)
foreach (x in case line.Role when "Assistant" then [1] else [] end |
  create (n)-[Assistant]->(p)
)
foreach (x in case line.Role when "Manager" then [1] else [] end |
  create (n)-[r:Manager]->(p)
)
```

Comment: ugh.  that seriously bites.  to do foreach loops is as bad as just hard-coding it. yuk!! I guess I'll look into the import tool.  thanks

Comment: I've looked into the import tool.  it offers a --into parameter which makes it clear that I need to import into a blank database.  jesus, they don't make this easy.  it means I can't update an existing database with it, which makes it quite useless.  or am I misunderstanding the docs on that parameter? I tried it.  it creates a whole new database.  very unhappy.

Comment: Another option is to create a separate csv file per relationship type.

Comment: Or to filter your csv file for the rel-type with `WITH line WHERE line.Role = "Manager" ... `

Comment: thanks for the suggestions guys.  in fact I'm generating the code from Excel anyway so I can hard-code the relationship creations.  it's just unfortunate that the syntax should be so inflexible, for what is a relatively small lexikon.

Answer (score 0):

Michael's answer stands, however, I've found that what I *can* do is specify an attribute to the relationship, like this:

```
load csv from 'file:/.../x.csv' as line 
match (p:Project {code: line[3]}) 
create (i:Individual {name: line[1]})-[r:Role { type: line[2] }]->(p)
```

and I can make Neo4j display the type attribute of the relationship instead of the label

Answer (score 0):

this question is old, but there is a post by Mark Needham

that provide a great and easy [solution](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2016/10/30/neo4j-create-dynamic-relationship-type/) using APOC

as follow

```
load csv with headers from "file:///people.csv" AS row
MERGE (p1:Person {name: row.node1})
MERGE (p2:Person {name: row.node2})

WITH p1, p2, row
CALL apoc.create.relationship(p1, row.relationship, {}, p2) YIELD rel

RETURN rel
```

note: the "YIELD rel" is essential and so for the return part