# how create relationship in neo4j use load csv,but the type of relation is variable

Tags: neo4j

this is the clause
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 20000 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://192.3.4.101:8080/export/rel.csv" AS row 
MATCH (a:Person{id:row.id}),(b:Place{id:row.place_id}) create (a)-[:row.relation_type]->(b)

this is the rel.csv file in the picture
mostly,user "create (a)-[:TYPE]->(b)" to create a relation
but how to create a relation as a field --relation_type in the csv file
this is the csv file, two kinds of relation type 
 
id,place_id,relation_type
141221199010000001,1,livein
141221199010000002,2,livein
141221199010000003,3,bornIn
141221199010000004,4,livein
141221199010000005,5,bornIn
141221199010000006,6,bornIn
141221199010000007,7,bornIn
141221199010000008,8,bornIn
141221199010000009,9,livein

Comment: but there a syntax error in the above clause ,"row.relation_type" as relation is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is not possible to specify relationship types in CSV.
See [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312417/how-to-specify-relationship-type-in-csv)

Comment: Thank you very much,you are right ,The relationshipType must be fixed value in the load csv clause