# Creating a metabolic pathway in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am attempting to create the glycolytic pathway shown in the image at the bottom of this question, in Neo4j, using these data:

*glycolysis_bioentities.csv*

```
name
α-D-glucose
glucose 6-phosphate
fructose 6-phosphate
"fructose 1,6-bisphosphate"
dihydroxyacetone phosphate
D-glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate
"1,3-bisphosphoglycerate"
3-phosphoglycerate
2-phosphoglycerate
phosphoenolpyruvate
pyruvate
hexokinase
glucose-6-phosphatase
phosphoglucose isomerase
phosphofructokinase
"fructose-bisphosphate aldolase, class I"
triosephosphate isomerase (TIM)
glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate dehydrogenase
phosphoglycerate kinase
phosphoglycerate mutase
enolase
pyruvate kinase
```

*glycolysis_relations.csv*

```
source,relation,target
α-D-glucose,substrate_of,hexokinase
hexokinase,yields,glucose 6-phosphate
glucose 6-phosphate,substrate_of,glucose-6-phosphatase
glucose-6-phosphatase,yields,α-D-glucose
glucose 6-phosphate,substrate_of,phosphoglucose isomerase
phosphoglucose isomerase,yields,fructose 6-phosphate
fructose 6-phosphate,substrate_of,phosphofructokinase
phosphofructokinase,yields,"fructose 1,6-bisphosphate"
"fructose 1,6-bisphosphate",substrate_of,"fructose-bisphosphate aldolase, class I"
"fructose-bisphosphate aldolase, class I",yields,D-glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate
D-glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate,substrate_of,glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate dehydrogenase
D-glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate,substrate_of,triosephosphate isomerase (TIM)
triosephosphate isomerase (TIM),yields,dihydroxyacetone phosphate
glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate dehydrogenase,yields,"1,3-bisphosphoglycerate"
"1,3-bisphosphoglycerate",substrate_of,phosphoglycerate kinase
phosphoglycerate kinase,yields,3-phosphoglycerate
3-phosphoglycerate,substrate_of,phosphoglycerate mutase
phosphoglycerate mutase,yields,2-phosphoglycerate
2-phosphoglycerate,substrate_of,enolase
enolase,yields,phosphoenolpyruvate
phosphoenolpyruvate,substrate_of,pyruvate kinase
pyruvate kinase,yields,pyruvate
```

This is what I have, thus far,

[image]

... using this cypher code (passed to `Cycli` or `cypher-shell`):

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/glycolysis_relations.csv" AS row
MERGE (s:Glycolysis {source: row.source})
MERGE (r:Glycolysis {relation: row.relation})
MERGE (t:Glycolysis {target: row.target})
FOREACH (x in case row.relation when "substrate_of" then [1] else [] end |
  MERGE (s)-[r:substrate_of]->(t)
)
FOREACH (x in case row.relation when "yields" then [1] else [] end |
  MERGE (s)-[r:yields]->(t)
  );
```

I'd like to create the fully-connected pathway, with captions on all the nodes.  Suggestions?

[image]

Comment: This Neo4j GraphGist (https://neo4j.com/graphgist/metabolic-pathways-as-graphs; code: https://portal.graphgist.org/graph_gists/metabolic-pathways-as-graphs/source) captures the essence of the problem; however, I'd like to have a more automated approach, where I can recreate metabolic pathways from data rather than hand-crafting the pathway.

Comment: I should credit that pathway image (Fig. 16.2): Berg JM et al. [L. Stryer] (2006) Biochemisry, p. 436. https://www.amazon.ca/Biochemistry-Jeremy-Berg/dp/0716787245.  I used an earlier version for my undergraduate degree (Hon. Biochem.), many years ago; it is an excellent text/reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UPDATED]

There are multiple issues and possible improvements:

1. The second `MERGE` should be deleted, since it creates orphaned nodes. A relationship type should not be tuned into a `Glycolysis` node, and such nodes would never be connected to any other nodes.
2. The 1st and 3rd `MERGE` clauses must use the same property name (say, `name`) for source and target nodes, or else the same chemical can end up with 2 nodes (with different property keys). This is why you ended up with nodes that did not have all the expected connections.
3. The APOC procedure [apoc.cypher.doIt](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_running_cypher_fragments) can be used to simplify somewhat the `MERGE` of relationships with dynamic names.
4. The `glycolysis_bioentities.csv` is not needed for this use case.

With the above changes, you end up with something like this, which will generate a connected graph that matches your input data:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/glycolysis_relations.csv" AS row
MERGE (s:Glycolysis {name: row.source})
MERGE (t:Glycolysis {name: row.target})
WITH s, t, row
CALL apoc.cypher.doIt(
  'MERGE (s)-[r:' + row.relation + ']->(t)',
  {s:s, t:t}) YIELD value
RETURN 1;
```

Comment: Nice - thank you so much!  I really appreciate the explanations, tips, code! :-D

Comment: Update: I noticed that re-running your code, with the APOC procedure, results in additional relationships added with each iteration; my version (sepatate "answer," below) -- which does not use APOC -- does not do this.  I'll try to look into this, later.

Comment: Yes, you are right that my original query would create duplicate relationships if it were run twice. I have updated my answer with a query that will not create duplicates (but it is a bit uglier than before).

Comment: To update others following this thread, @cybersham's original answer was identical to this one: http://markhneedham.com/blog/2016/10/30/neo4j-create-dynamic-relationship-type/ [... `WITH s, t, row CALL apoc.create.relationship(s, row.relation, {}, t) YIELD rel RETURN COUNT(*)` ...].  However, that code caused additional (duplicate) relations to be added, with each iteration (rerunning) of the code block -- i.e. rerunning the .cypher script.  Much appreciation -- again -- to @cybersam for providing the updated solution!  :-)

Comment: I looked into this a bit more: it appears, https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/271, that there is a solution to your original answer. If you replace the corresponding line of your original code with the following (note the addition of the 5th property, `{},`), it appears to work, as intended: `CALL apoc.merge.relationship(s, row.relation, {}, {}, t) YIELD rel`

Answer (score 3):

@cybersam's answer is excellent, providing the most elegant solution (once again: thank you!) -- please upvote that accepted answer.

Since this question/answer/topic is likely to be of interest to others, I wanted to mention that my code (based on this SO thread, [How to specify relationship type in CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312417/how-to-specify-relationship-type-in-csv), and modified per the hints provided by @cybersam) now works, and show the result:

**Solution 1 (my original post, updated):**

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/glycolysis_relations.csv" AS row
MERGE (s:Glycolysis {name:row.source})
MERGE (t:Glycolysis {name:row.target})
FOREACH (x in case row.relation when "substrate_of" then [1] else [] end |
  MERGE (s)-[r:substrate_of]->(t)
)
FOREACH (x in case row.relation when "yields" then [1] else [] end |
  MERGE (s)-[r:yields]->(t)
  );
```

**Solution 2 (cybersam's, updated):**

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/glycolysis_relations.csv" AS row
MERGE (s:Metabolism:Glycolysis {name: row.source})
MERGE (t:Metabolism:Glycolysis {name: row.target})
WITH s, t, row
  // "Bug" -- additional duplicate relations with each iteration of this statement/script:
  // CALL apoc.create.relationship(s, row.relation, {}, t) YIELD rel
  // Solution: 
  // https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/271
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47808421/neo4j-load-csv-to-create-dynamic-relationship-types
  CALL apoc.merge.relationship(s, row.relation, {}, {}, t) YIELD rel
RETURN COUNT(*);
```

Both solutions generate the identical graph, below. :-D

[image: neo4j_glycolytc_pathway]

Comment: A nice solution, replicable in other pathways. Then you can have intersecting graphs and lots of interesting opportunities. For instance, glycolysis produces ATP whereas other pathways consume it. You're working with substrates and products; adding enzymes and their kinetics (Km, etc) could identify rates and limiting steps. I wish I had these tools when I was still in the lab!

Comment: Precisely!  This is part of a larger initiative of mine; in addition to other metabolic pathways, you can also add cellular signaling pathways (relevant, e.g., to regulation), plus other data extracted rom various sources (e.g. PubMed). In the example above, isozymes of hexokinase are associated with T2D, insulin resistance, hemolytic anaemia, cancer.  Elsewhere, variants / quantities of various bioentities are relevant to human disease, intervention, modeling ...

Comment: Use can use not just PubMed, but,as you seem to imply, OMIM and the entire Entrez data mart. For those not familiar, here's a great example of a federated query tapping many Entrez resources: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/search/?term=fructose

Answer (score 0):

If permitted, I'd like to post one more follow-on answer -- my reason being that currently there is very little out there on recreating metabolic pathways in Neo4j, and the following will provide a complete summary under this
StackOverflow title/subject, "Creating a metabolic pathway in Neo4j".

Like my *Glycolysis* pathway, above, I recreated in Neo4j the *TCA* (*citric acid cycle* | *Kreb's cycle*) pathway:

[image: TCA cycle]

[TCA cycle image source: https://metabolicpathways.stanford.edu/]

An issue that arose during the creation of my TCA pathway graph was that the one of the nodes (the enzyme, "aconitase") was used twice, so during the graph creation `MERGE` merged the common node `aconitase` as a single entity, resulting in this layout,

[image: aconitase - 'incorrect' layout]

... not this one, as desired,

[image: aconitase - 'correct' layout]

My solution to that issue was to create the "TCA graph" using node properties, to temporarily differentially-tag the affected source and target nodes (later removing those tags, after the graph was properly created).

I also added a `:Metabolism` label, so that I could select the individual pathways (`:Glycolysis` | `:TCA`) or the complete metabolic network (`:Metabolism`), as desired.

Lastly, I needed to connect the two pathways (`:Glycolysis` | `:TCA`) through their common node, `pyruvate`, which I was able to do through an APOC procedure (here, appended to the end of my `glycolysis.cql` (Cypher) script.

Here are my CSV data files, *.cql Cypher scripts, script execution, and the resultant graph.

**glycolysis.csv:**

```
source,relation,target
α-D-glucose,substrate_of,hexokinase
hexokinase,yields,glucose 6-phosphate
glucose 6-phosphate,substrate_of,glucose-6-phosphatase
glucose-6-phosphatase,yields,α-D-glucose
glucose 6-phosphate,substrate_of,phosphoglucose isomerase
phosphoglucose isomerase,yields,fructose 6-phosphate
fructose 6-phosphate,substrate_of,phosphofructokinase
phosphofructokinase,yields,"fructose 1,6-bisphosphate"
"fructose 1,6-bisphosphate",substrate_of,"fructose-bisphosphate aldolase, class I"
"fructose-bisphosphate aldolase, class I",yields,D-glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate
D-glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate,substrate_of,glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate dehydrogenase
D-glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate,substrate_of,triosephosphate isomerase (TIM)
triosephosphate isomerase (TIM),yields,dihydroxyacetone phosphate
glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate dehydrogenase,yields,"1,3-bisphosphoglycerate"
"1,3-bisphosphoglycerate",substrate_of,phosphoglycerate kinase
phosphoglycerate kinase,yields,3-phosphoglycerate
3-phosphoglycerate,substrate_of,phosphoglycerate mutase
phosphoglycerate mutase,yields,2-phosphoglycerate
2-phosphoglycerate,substrate_of,enolase
enolase,yields,phosphoenolpyruvate
phosphoenolpyruvate,substrate_of,pyruvate kinase
pyruvate kinase,yields,pyruvate
```

**tca.csv:**

```
source,relation,target,tag1,tag2
pyruvate,substrate_of,pyruvate dehydrogenase,,
pyruvate dehydrogenase,yields,acetyl CoA,,
acetyl CoA,substrate_of,citrate synthase,,
oxaloacetate,substrate_of,citrate synthase,,
citrate synthase,yields,citrate,,
citrate,substrate_of,aconitase,,1
aconitase,yields,cis-aconitate,1,
cis-aconitate,substrate_of,aconitase,,2
aconitase,yields,isocitrate,2,
isocitrate,substrate_of,isocitrate dehydrogenase,,
isocitrate dehydrogenase,yields,α-ketoglutarate,,
α-ketoglutarate,substrate_of,α-ketoglutarate dehydrogenase,,
α-ketoglutarate dehydrogenase,yields,succinyl-CoA,,
succinyl-CoA,substrate_of,succinyl-CoA synthetase,,
succinyl-CoA synthetase,yields,succinate,,
succinate,substrate_of,succinate dehydrogenase,,
succinate dehydrogenase,yields,fumarate,,
fumarate,substrate_of,fumarase,,
fumarase,yields,S-malate,,
S-malate,substrate_of,malate dehydrogenase,,
malate dehydrogenase,yields,oxaloacetate,,
```

"tag1" and "tag"2 in "tsv.csv" are used to uniquely those source and target nodes, when they are created via the "tca.cql" script:

**tca.cql:**

```
// CREATE INDICES:
CREATE INDEX ON :Metabolism(name);
CREATE INDEX ON :TCA(name);

// CREATE GRAPH:
// USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/mnt/Vancouver/Programming/data/metabolism/tca.csv" AS row
MERGE (s:Metabolism:TCA {name: row.source, tag:COALESCE(row.tag1, '')})
MERGE (t:Metabolism:TCA {name: row.target, tag:COALESCE(row.tag2, '')})
WITH s, t, row
  CALL apoc.merge.relationship(s, row.relation, {}, {}, t) YIELD rel
  REMOVE s.tag, t.tag
RETURN COUNT(*);
```

**glycolysis.cql:**

```
// CREATE INDICES:
CREATE INDEX ON :Metabolism(name);
CREATE INDEX ON :Glycolysis(name);

// CREATE GRAPH:
//USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/mnt/Vancouver/Programming/data/metabolism/glycolysis.csv" AS row
MERGE (s:Metabolism:Glycolysis {name: row.source})
MERGE (t:Metabolism:Glycolysis {name: row.target})
WITH s, t, row
  CALL apoc.merge.relationship(s, row.relation, {}, {}, t) YIELD rel
RETURN COUNT(*);

// MERGE COMMON NODE (GLYCOLYSIS: PYRUVATE; TCA: PYRUVATE):
// As presented, run "tca.cql" first, then "glycolysis.cql"

MATCH (g:Glycolysis), (t:TCA) WHERE g.name = t.name
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes([g,t]) YIELD node
  RETURN node;
```

**Script execution:**

```
$ cat tca.cql |  cypher-shell -u *** -p ***
  COUNT(*)
  21

$ cat glycolysis.cql |  cypher-shell -u *** -p ***
  COUNT(*)
  22
  node
  (:Metabolism:TCA:Glycolysis {name: "pyruvate"})

$
```

**Neo4j graph (`:Metabolism` view):**

[image: Neo4j Browser: Glycolysis + TCA metabolic psathways]

Comment: I provide some updates relevant to the examples above in my July 2019 research blog post "KEGG Pathways Representation in NetworkX": https://persagen.com/2019/07/30/kegg_pathways_networkx.html