# Neo4j and metabolic pathway

Tags: neo4j

I wanna make a metabolic pathway in Neo4j a lot like this one [similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682338/creating-a-metabolic-pathway-in-neo4j)

but bigger I have around 150 reactions with side products. I don't even know where to start. When I installed neo4j and wanted to import a csv file I can't even find folder where neo4j keeps the files so I could copy the csv file there.

Is there a template for something like what Im looking?

Sorry for the general question but I am totally lost.

Cheers guys!

Answer (score 0):

> In Neo4j Desktop’s Manage pane, you should see the button for Open
>   Folder in the upper panel. Right next to that button is a dropdown
>   arrow button. If you click that, you will see a menu of options for
>   different folders. Choose the Import folder.

[ https://neo4j.com/developer/desktop-csv-import/ ]

Comment: Okay I need to get the desktop app. Thanks! What about the templates?

Comment: I imported the file but when I copy paste the code in the neo4j it says : "Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound: There is no procedure with the name `apoc.merge.relationship` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed."

Comment: @NoobProgrammer You need install apoc library: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures#installation-with-neo4j-desktop